# How do I restrict MySQL user from dropping, and adding tables and databases

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find the SQL command to create a user that can read and write in tables found in one database, but is not allowed to do anything else.

Also if you can recommend other limits I should add to the MySQL user I would appreciate it.

The reason I am asking is because one of my tables was dropped and I have no idea how... I think it's PHP but I am not sure... Maybe someone connected via my SSH... The thing is all my mysql logs are empty and no evidence of a another user trying to do something are to be found in the other logs...

So for now I am assuming there is something wrong with my PHP... This is why I would like to limit it to only adding, removing, and dropping rows and content in the rows... But not more. So that I don't loose my table again or my other DBs.

Comment: If you have PHP admin, it should be fairly easy, to do. But, you haven't stated if you have it or not

Comment: Have you checked your code for possible susceptibility to an SQL injection attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the user using `CREATE USER`, and specify the privileges using `GRANT`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html ([click here for a list of MySQL privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html))

If you have phpMyAdmin running, the interface will give you a complete set of privileges to check/uncheck :)

For a basic web application, you'll only need SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE :)

If you think there was a security issue with your application, [check this page to know more](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/five-common-web-application-vulnerabilities).

Comment: I did not install it [phpMyAdmin] to limit the possibility of being hacked.

Comment: Then process MySQL queries (`CREATE USER` and `GRANT`) from the command line (mysql client). You just need to know the syntax :) You can start a mysql client with the `mysql` command. Use the `--user` flag to set a username, and `-p` to warn the client you'll have to enter a password afterwards.

Comment: I am using Laravel and it is supposed to protect my app... Maybe I need to configure something? Not sure I will check. I have also added access log... I did not have it configured so I have no idea if it was coming from there.

Comment: There is the Laravel documentation about its internal security : http://four.laravel.com/docs/security ; I don't use this FW, therefore I can't be more useful :p

Comment: That's ok... :) This was a question on MySQL.